# What is the history of Golang's syntax?

Tags: syntax, go

I'm trying to use Golang and i found its syntax very interesting :

```
var a int = 10

b := 10

for {
 ...
}

func hello() world() int{

}
```

These syntaxes make me very interested in it, is there anyone knows its history of syntax ?

Or why they design it this way.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you would be better off asking on golang-nuts (the main mailing list), where you could get answers from the creators themselves.

Comment: http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html#different_syntax

Comment: In Go's Declaration Syntax (http://blog.golang.org/2010/07/gos-declaration-syntax.html) the creators explain the reasoning behind the type-after-name syntax.

Comment: and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28programming_language%29